# Matrix with given condition $a+b+c+d=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that if $a+b+c+d=0$ then $\begin{vmatrix}
a &b  &c  &d \\ 
b & c & d & a\\ 
 c&  d&  a& b\\ 
 d&  a&  b& c
\end{vmatrix}=0$.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Take any single row and add up all other rows onto it.

eg: take $R_{4}$ and do

$$ R_{4} \to R_{4} + R_{3} + R_{2} + R_{1}$$

Comment: comment: works for column as well